# Jquery Set Toggle Visibility per same class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I wanted to show a free label  when someone hover on the product however when I set the free label to 
`visibility:hidden` it doesn't work . When I remove it , it works however it shows up on all products not individually on hover

```
$(function() {
  $('.product').hover(function() {
    if ($('.free_label').is(':hidden')) {
      $('.free_label').hide();
    } else {
      $('.free_label').show();
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dptp6bj9/

I wanted to show the free label on hover

Comment: What you're saying with that code is "if elements with class `free_label` are hidden, hide them" which doesn't seem right.

Comment: even if I reverse it would still not work

Comment: What's wrong with CSS only: https://jsfiddle.net/dptp6bj9/3/ ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the **`visibilty: visible`** of **`free_label`** on hover like below

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gaphgoeg/1/)**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.product').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.free_label').css('visibility', 'visible');
  }, function() {
    $('.free_label').css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.free_label {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 30px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.planning_domain {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">product1
  <div class="free_label">FREE!</div>
</div>

<div class="product">product2
  <div class="free_label">FREE!</div>
</div>

<div class="product">product3
  <div class="free_label">FREE!</div>
</div>
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: awesome thanks so find function is the one that select individual element?

Comment: This code is redundant. You don't need to set all `.free_label` to hidden on mouseenter nor on mouseleave. Anyway, better would be to just use CSS pseudo class `:hover`

Comment: @JeVic find is used to [get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: @A.Wolff I agree with your CSS pseudo class `:hover` solution but as a jQuery solution I think you have to set all `. free_label ` to hidden on mouseenter

Comment: No because you are already set them all as hidden on mouseleave

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code, look here https://jsfiddle.net/x1ae4jqk/

```
$(function() {
  $('.product').hover(function() {
    if ($('.free_label').hasClass('hidden')) {
      $('.free_label').removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
      $('.free_label').addClass('hidden');
    }
  });
});
```